# VoiceOver left and right arrow keys are reserved for predefined behavior. How to override?

Tags: safari, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, wcag

For VoiceOver, the left and right arrow keys seemed to be reserved for 2 things:

1. By default, the left and right arrow keys put focus on the letter of
   whatever the focus is on.

   EX:
   [image: Focus on a letter]
2. If you turn on quick-nav (left and right arrow key), the left and
   right arrow keys are used to go through the entire content of the
   page, whether focusable or not.

   So what is the consensus on whether specific keys should be overriden? In this example, the overriden feature does not work as expected because VoiceOver has a predefined behavior for the left and right arrow keys.

NOTE: This issue only occurs for VoiceOver + Safari. You can try it with this example of accessible tabs (which with VO and Safari is not accessible).https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-2/tabs.html

Comment: There are a few 'obvious' keyboard-controls that are disabled by default on Mac OS. Have a look here: http://www.weba11y.com/blog/2014/07/07/keyboard-navigation-in-mac-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

## So what is the consensus on whether specific keys should be overriden?

I am providing general advice as I do not know your use-case (you show tabs but there could be other components you are working on).

It is perfectly acceptable to over-ride keys with custom functionality that improves your website / web app (in fact it is encouraged) with a big caveat!

There needs to be an easy way to both **switch shortcut keys on and off** and give the user the **option to change the key bindings** to what they want via an options menu or similar.

Old advice used to be that there are 'safe' shortcut keys you could use, but a lot of users change their key bindings to meet there needs (it isn't just screen readers but all assistive devices you need to consider) and new screen readers are introduced that use different sets of keys, making this advice obsolete and a bad practice.

Also consider adding some guidance (if your design allows) on the shortcut keys you have implemented to make it easier for people to use certain elements of your site as you cannot assume someone will automatically know what keys to use where.